# POST response error after collection.insert with NodeJS Mongo module

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've got this error when trying to POST

```
>         process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
>                                       ^
>     
>     TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer
>         at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.end (_http_outgoing.js:524:11)
```

Errors shows that something's wrong with *utils* and *cursor* both from mongodb module, but what are they?

Everything works nice on GET but brakes on POST (postman and passing as text {"name":"Computer","price":2500}) - i cannot trace which module or instance is braking the code.

This is my conn with db:

```
// Our primary interface for the MongoDB instance
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// Used in order verify correct return values
var assert = require('assert');

var connect = function (databaseName, callBack) {

    var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/' + databaseName;

    MongoClient.connect(url,
        function (error, database) {

            assert.equal(null, error);

            console.log("Succesfully connected to MongoDB instance!");

            callBack(database);
        });
};


exports.find = function (databaseName, collectionName, query, callback) {
    connect(databaseName, function (database) {

        var collection = database.collection(collectionName);

        collection.find(query).toArray(
            // Callback method
            function (err, documents) {

                // Make sure nothing went wrong
                assert.equal(err, null);

                // Print all the documents which we found, if any
                console.log("MongoDB returned the following documents:");
                console.dir(documents)

                callback(err, documents);

                // Close the database connection to free resources
                database.close();
            })
    })
};

exports.insert = function (databaseName, collectionName, object, callback) {
    connect(databaseName, function (database) {
        var collection = database.collection(collectionName);
        collection.insert(document, {w: 1}, function (err, documents) {
            console.log("Added a new document");
            console.log(documents[0]);
            callback(err, documents[0]);
        });
    })
};

exports.remove = function (databaseName, collectionName, object, callback) {
    connect(databaseName, function (database) {
        var collection = database.collection(collectionName);
        collection.remove(object, function (err, result) {
            callback(err, result);
            database.close();
        });
    })
};
```

Comment: I posted a response below, but I may or may not have fully understood your problem. If it doesn't resolve it, post your FULL stack trace and add the where your exported methods are getting called so that we know what the callback really is.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is actually pretty straightforward, so I'm surprised that you're not getting a better error message.

In your code:

```
collection.insert(document, {w: 1}, function (err, documents) {
  console.log("Added a new document");
  console.log(documents[0]); // I expect this to log undefined
  callback(err, documents[0]);
});
```

The second argument passed into the `collection.insert` callback is actually a results object, not the documents that were inserted. So, `documents[0]` ends up being `undefined` because it's not an array of documents. Thus, when you trying to send `undefined` as a response, it's failing.

If you intention is to pass the newly created documents, you're going to have to use the `result` object to get the _id and attach it to the document you inserted.

As a side note, I would consider keeping a connection open to your database rather than creating a new connection every time you want to talk with Mongo.